# Is my interpretation of the return correct?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, rewards, sutton-barto, return

Sutton and Barto 2018 define the discounted return $G_t$ the following way ([p 55](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xeUDVGWGUUv1-ccUMAZHJLej2C7aAFWY/view)):

[image]

Is my interpretation correct?

[image]

Or should all "1" be in the same column?

Answer (score 3):

Your table is almost correct. It is a minor difference, you should not have a $R_0$, the top row, leftmost column of numbers should be empty. That is because the first reward is $R_1$ (a result of taking action $A_0$ in state $S_0$). The alignment of the columns on the right hand side *is* correct though.

It might help to add the time step number at the top. But the important detail is that $G_t$ is a measure of all *future* rewards.

For instance it should always be zero when you reach a terminal state, which is what your example shows. Whilst it is quite common to receive a reward at the end of an episode (i.e. whilst arriving at a terminal state), also as your example shows.

The decision to have reward time step match that of *next state* is a convention that can be altered. A few RL sources, but not Sutton & Barto, will have reward on same time step as state and action that decided it, and thus $R_0$ will exist. The reward of 1 for reaching the terminal state would then be 1 time step earlier in your table, and there would be no $R_4$. The definition of $G_t$ would need to change to match ($G_t = R_t + \gamma G_{t+1})$, as well as other equations. That would change your table also - the reward sequence (top row) would shift to the left.